# Random Modules on Python

Tags: python, random, module

I am trying to create a program on Python which shows a random number every 3 seconds for 30 seconds. I know how to do it the long way like this:

```
import random

print (random.randint(0,100))

from time import sleep

sleep(3) # Time in seconds
```

I did this ten times. Is there any way to make this process shorter?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *"make this process shorter"*?

Comment: By making it shorter, I mean not having to write it all out 10 times.

Comment: Then the answers below may solve your problem. **Read about loops** in Python, they are essential in programming.

Comment: Thank You to everyone who posted an answer. I found they all worked. I really appreciate it. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Use looping, which is designed for just such requirements:

```
import random
import time
for i in range(10):
    print(random.randint(0, 100))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
for x in range(0,10):
    print (random.randint(0,100))
    sleep(3)
```